# Linker Error with packages installed through Conan

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, linker-errors, conan

I am trying to get OpenCV to work with Conan but it doesn't work.

I am on Windows 10.

Default Conan profile:

```
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=msvc
compiler.cppstd=20
compiler.runtime=dynamic
compiler.version=193
os=Windows
```

Content of my project folder:

conanfile.txt

```
[requires]
opencv/4.5.5

[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

project(minimal LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED VERSION 4.5.5)

add_executable(prog main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(prog PRIVATE
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)

target_include_directories(prog PRIVATE 
    ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat mat{};
    return 0;
}
```

I configure the project with this command:

```
conan install . --output-folder=build --build=missing

cmake -B build --preset conan-default
```

Then, I try to build with this command:

```
cmake --build --preset conan-release
```

but I get this error:

```
 main.cpp
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl cv::Mat::Mat(void)" (??0Mat@cv@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main [C:\Users\redbox\Desktop\projects\opencvexample\build\prog.vcxproj]
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl cv::Mat::~Mat(void)" (??1Mat@cv@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main [C:\Users\redbox\Desktop\projects\opencvexample\build\prog.vcxproj]
C:\Users\redbox\Desktop\projects\opencvexample\build\Release\prog.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals [C:\Users\desktop\Desktop\projects\opencvexample\build\prog.vcxproj]
```

I also tried to compile a basic program with QT installed through Conan, but then a similar error occurs. Curiously, this error does not seem to occur with libraries that are rather small, like Zlib (the [basic Zlib example](https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/consuming_packages/build_simple_cmake_project.html) from the Conan example works fine)

I don't know what's going wrong here.

Comment: You are linking with the bare libraries, but this is not correct. You need to link with the CMake targets, ``target_link_libraries(prog PRIVATE OpenCV::OpenCV)`` (the exact name of the target I don't know, it will be displayed when ``find_package()`` finds the Conan package. The target is able to bring and link the transitive dependencies, while the bare libraries not.

Comment: `CMakeDeps` doesn't define `OpenCV_LIBS` (recipe could be fixed, because it's supposed to mimic official CMake config file). Link imported targets instead, they are correct in opencv recipe: `target_link_libraries(prog PRIVATE opencv_core)`

Comment: For asking questions about the project, support, you can better use Github issues in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues

Comment: @drodri Your comment helped me somewhat in that CMake now finds OpenCV but now a whole array of other problems arose... I'll investigate and may ask a separate question

Comment: Better, post them as Github issues as recommended above, the format is better suited for support questions like this one

Comment: After https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/pull/20729, `target_link_libraries(prog PRIVATE ${OpenCV_LIBS})` should work. Though, you have to update opencv recipe with latest revision (add `-u` option in conan install). Maybe wait few hours, because this new recipe revision might not be available yet in conancenter remote.